# Check for cycles whose weights don't sum up to 0

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a connected graph `g` with `n` vertices and `m` edges.

Each edge can be traversed from both directions, while traversing them in one direction their weight is positive, traverse them in the other direction and their weight is negative.

So for every edge `u` -> `v` with weight `w` there exists an edge `v` -> `u` with weight `-w`.

**My goal:**

For a given vertex `v`, check if there exists a path back to `v` (a cycle) so that the sum of the edge weights of that path is not equal to `0`. If such a path exists then output the minimal number of edges of such a path, otherwise output `"all cycles are fine"`.

**Examples:**

An example where all paths from `v` to `v` sum up to `0`. The output is `"all cycles are fine"`:

[image: Example 1]

An example where there exist paths from `v` to `v` whose edges sum up to something which isn't equal to `0`. The minimal number of edges of such a path is 4 in this example:

[image: Example 2]

**My current approach:**

Find all paths/cycles from vertex `v` to itself and check if all of them sum up to `0`. I have problems finding all paths/cycles in an efficient manner, is there a more elegant solution or should I try to find the most efficient algorithm for finding all paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this problem is equivalent to "For a given vertex v, for any other vertex's, check if all paths from v to that vertex have a same weight".

I guess you can do that by BFS, just mark vertex's with the distance from v, and check if there's different distance when traversing.

In other words, since all the distances from the starting vertex to a certain vertex should be the same, you can just create labels with that distance for each vertex. From the given starting vertex, BFS traverse all the vertex's. For each vertex `v` when you traverse the graph, check all the edge whose tail is `v`. Calculate the label of `v` plus the weight of the edge and get a value `x` (`v` must have been labeled). For the head vertex `w` of the edge, there is two possibility:

1. `w` is not labeled. Then label `w` with value `x`.
2. `w` has been labeled. In this case, compare `x` and the label of `w`.

   - If they are the same, continue checking.
   - Otherwise, you have a circle with minimal number of edges, since you are doing a BFS. Stop immediately.

When all the edges starting from `v` is checked, go to the next vertex in BFS. If all vertex has passed the test, no such circle exists.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting idea, all paths from `v` to a vertex `w` should have the same length since if there are 2 paths with a different length from `v` to `w` we can use one to get to `w` and the other to get back to `v`, the sum of edge weights must be unequal to 0 because of our assumption that the lengths of the 2 paths differ. Now to the second part, the goal is to check that all paths from `v` to every vertex `w` have the same length, could you elaborate how this could be accomplished by using BFS?

Comment: All right, I understand how we can check for cycles which don't sum up to 0 with BFS, what I don't understand is how I can be sure that the circle has a minimal number of edges? And how do I determine the length (sum of edge weights) of that minimal circle?

Comment: By using BFS, you are aware of the number of edges from the starting vertex to current vertex. In this case, you can make another label `n`: least number of edges from starting vertex. When you meet a vertex `w` which has different distance, as mentioned above, you have a circle whose number of edges is the sum of two part: `n` of w and the number of edges from starting point to `v`. The second part must be smallest since we are doing BFS. For the first part, try all possible `w` and pick a minimal one.

Comment: The algorithm you described works for almost all cases, there are cases where the order in which the vertices are traversed matter (stopping immediately after finding a "bad circle" yields the wrong answer). My final solution does a full BFS, stores all "bad circle" sizes and outputs the minimum.