# Check if all paths from a vertex v to another vertex w are of the same length

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a connected graph `g` with `n` vertices and `m` edges.

Each edge can be traversed from both directions, while traversing them in one direction their weight is positive, traverse them in the other direction and their weight is negative.

So for every edge `u` -> `v` with weight `w` there exists an edge `v` -> `u` with weight `-w`.

**My goal:**

For a given vertex `v`, check if there exists a path back to `v` (a cycle) so that the sum of the edge weights of that path is not equal to `0`. If such a path exists then output the minimal number of edges of such a path, otherwise output `"all cycles are fine"`.

**Examples:**

An example where all paths from `v` to `v` sum up to `0`. The output is `"all cycles are fine"`:

[image: Example 1]

An example where there exist paths from `v` to `v` whose edges sum up to something which isn't equal to `0`. The minimal number of edges of such a path is 4 in this example:

[image: Example 2]

**My current approach:**

The problem seems to be equivalent to checking if all paths from a given vertex `v` to any other vertex `w` are of equal length, if this is true then "all cycles are fine", otherwise I output the length of the shortest cycle which breaks the condition. I have trouble finding an efficient algorithm for testing this condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple algorithm to check if there exists a "wrong cycle" that passes through a vertex A is to run a BFS from A, then see which vertices B are visited at least twice with different costs. If no B exists, then all cycles are good, otherwise there is a bad cycle with size (edges until first visit to B) + (edges until visit to B with a different cost). This BFS visits every vertex at most twice, so the complexity is still linear.

Therefore, this problem could be solved with a BFS from every vertex in the graph. Of course, maybe this can be made more efficient; what is adequate depends on the sizes of n and m.

Comment: Thanks for your help, full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141136/check-for-cycles-whose-weights-dont-sum-up-to-0/44141592#44141592